# If $a^4+64=0$ and $a^2 \ne-4a-8$, what is the value of $a^2-4a$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> If $a^4+64=0$ and $a^2 \ne-4a-8$, what is the value of $a^2-4a$?

I tried to add $-16a^2$ to both sides and doing some algebra but it didnt help much.

Comment: If $a^4=-64$, then $a^2=\pm8i$. What is $(\pm8i)!$ supposed to mean? The extension per $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: This is a high school question,I think it is supposed to be simple.

Comment: By "$!=$", do you mean $\ne$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  I believe $!=$ is supposed to be $\neq$.  OP, please confirm.

Comment: Yes it means "not equal".Sorry for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that $a^4+64=(a^2+4a+8)(a^2-4a+8)$. So if one of the items on the right is not $0$, then $\dots$

Comment: How could you seperate it like that? Yes the answer is -8,thank you.

Comment: Great!Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: You are welcome. You can check the factorization by multiplying out. You can maybe discover it by $a^4+64=(a^2+8)^2 -(4a)^2$, difference of squares. Your adding $16a^2$ to both sides was a great idea, would have worked.

Comment: Super @Andre Nicolas . Cannot be quite without congratulating on the answer .

Comment: How can I mark the question as solved?

Comment: clicking tick symbol .

Comment: (Aka the "check mark" near the voting arrows")

Comment: It appears on the side of the answer . See to it that it changes green

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to find the factorization, it is very similar to completing the square, we have $$\begin{align*}a^4 + 64 &= a^4 + 16a^2 + 64 - 16a^2\\ &= (a^2 + 8)^2 - 16a^2 \\ &= (a^2 - 4a + 8)(a^2 + 4a + 8)\end{align*}$$

See also http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Sophie_Germain_Identity

Comment: Thanks for all answers and comments.I spent more than 20 minutes on this question.I think I should sleep :)